# How to execute task concurrently with other statements in an always block?

Tags: verilog, xilinx-ise

I am writing code for 8*4 RAM in Verilog. For each binary cell of memory, I am using an SR flip-flop. Initially, each cell is assigned 1'bx. The logic seems to be correct, but the output isn't. It is probably because statements are not getting executed concurrently. Can anyone suggest how can I get the task SRFlipFlop to get executed concurrently with other statements?

```
module memory(addr, read_data, rw, write_data, clk);
// read_data is the data read
// rw specifies read or write operation. 1 for read and 0 for write
// write data is the data to be written
// addr is the address to be written or read    

task SRFlipFlop;
input d,r,s,clk; // d is the value initially stored
output q;  
begin
case({s,r})
{1'b0,1'b0}: q<=d;
{1'b0,1'b1}: q<=1'b0;
{1'b1,1'b0}: q<=1'b1;
{1'b1,1'b1}: q<=1'bx;
endcase
end
endtask

task decoder;     // a 3 to 8 line decoder
input [2:0] A;
input E;
output [7:0] D;
if (!E)
    D <= 16'b0000000000000000;
else
    begin
        case (A)
            3'b000 : D <= 8'b00000001;
            3'b001 : D <= 8'b00000010;
            3'b010 : D <= 8'b00000100;
            3'b011 : D <= 8'b00001000;
            3'b100 : D <= 8'b00010000;
            3'b101 : D <= 8'b00100000;
            3'b110 : D <= 8'b01000000;
            3'b111 : D <= 8'b10000000;
        endcase
    end
endtask


output reg [3:0] read_data;
input [3:0] write_data;
input [2:0] addr;
input rw, clk;
reg [3:0] memory [7:0];
reg [3:0] r [7:0];
reg [3:0] s [7:0];
reg [3:0] intermediate;
reg [3:0] select [7:0];
reg [7:0] out;
reg [7:0] out1;
integer i,j,k,l;
initial 
  begin
    for (i = 0; i <= 7; i=i+1) 
        begin
            for (j = 0; j <= 3; j=j+1) 
                begin
                 memory[i][j] = 1'bx;
                 r[i][j] = 1'b0;
                 s[i][j] = 1'b0;
                 select[i][j] = 1'b0;
                end
        end
  end
  always @(posedge clk)
  begin
    decoder(addr, 1'b1, out);
     for (i = 0; i <= 7; i=i+1)
        begin
            if (out[i] == 1'b1)
                begin
                for (j = 0; j <= 3; j=j+1)
                    begin
                        select[i][j] <= 1'b1;
                        s[i][j] <= write_data[j] & !rw & select[i][j];
                        r[i][j] <= !write_data[j] & !rw & select[i][j];
                        SRFlipFlop(memory[i][j],r[i][j],s[i][j],clk,intermediate);
                        memory[i][j] <= intermediate;
                        read_data[j] <= memory[i][j];
                    end
                end
        end
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Can you explain what you think it is that the "j" for loop is doing?

Comment: `select`  is never set back to zero, can that be the cause? In fact, `select` doesn't seem to to anything productive, there could be some logic bug here. You should also try to limit the amount of tasks you use, in some cases compilers might struggle with synthesis for tasks. To me, implementing the SRFF as a module makes much more sense.

Comment: Each memory address has a word of 4 bits. j is just the loop variable to carry out operations on each bit of the 4-bit word

Comment: If I implement SRFlipFlop as a module, how can I use it in an `always` block?

Comment: No, modules are meant to be instantiated, not called. See this answer for a complete explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354957/how-can-i-instantiate-a-module-inside-an-if-statement-in-verilog/30355723#30355723

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code style is very software-oriented. Personally I like to know how my code will look as a circuit, so instead of using nested for loops and tasks I will use modules and generate-loops to create my circuits.

I have not been able to make your code work, but I suspect that the error is in the fact that s and r are not reset to zero on every iteration.

I have created a functioning design here:
http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Guc

Instead of using the initial block to initialize values I have added an asynchronous reset.

The SRFF-task has been converted to a module. A RAMblock module instantiates four SRFF-modules. 8 RAMblocks are instantiated in the memory module.

I have converted your packed(`reg [] a []`) arrays into unpacked arrays(`reg [][] a`) to be able to perform bitwise operations on several bits without for-loops.

If you have questions about the code, feel free to message me.

Edit: Perhaps the most important thing to note in this design is that I separate the sequential circuitry from the combinatorial. This way it is much easier to control what should be updated on the posedge of clk and what should just be a combinatorial reaction to the changes performed at the posedge.