# Controlling 4 motors using FPGA

Tags: verilog, motordriver

I'm trying to control 4 motors using FPGA. (Verilog HDL)
I made a code using always block and custom module(which controls one servo motor, and it's input values-L_CTRL and R_CTRL determines whether servo motor spins one step to left or right)

Here is custom module code:

```
module Servo(CLK, RESETN, L_CTRL, R_CTRL, SERVO);

input CLK;
input RESETN, L_CTRL, R_CTRL;
output SERVO;
integer REG, CNT;
reg L, R;
reg SERVO;

always @(posedge RESETN or posedge CLK)
begin
    if (RESETN) CNT = 0;
    else
    if (CNT >= 199) CNT = 0;
    else CNT = CNT + 1;
end

always @(posedge RESETN or posedge CLK)
begin
    if (RESETN)
        REG = 15;
    else
    begin
    L <= L_CTRL; R <= R_CTRL;
    if (L == 0 & L_CTRL & REG > 7)
        REG = REG - 1;
    else if (R == 0 & R_CTRL & REG < 23)
        REG = REG + 1;
    end
end

always @(CNT or REG)
begin
if (CNT < REG)
    SERVO = 1;
else
    SERVO = 0;
end
endmodule
```

and I made code for controlling 4 motors:

```
module Servo_Motor(direction,CLK,RESETN,SERVO);
    input [1:0]direction;
    input CLK, RESETN;

    reg L_CTRL, R_CTRL;
    reg [3:0] SERVO;
    output [3:0] SERVO;
    //servo0, servo1->x_axis
    //servo2, servo3->y_axis

    always @(posedge RESETN or posedge CLK)
    begin
        if(direction==2'b01)//east
        begin
            L_CTRL<=0; R_CTRL<=1;
            Servo S0(CLK, RESETN, L_CTRL, R_CTRL, SERVO[0], enable_0);
            Servo S1(CLK, RESETN, L_CTRL, R_CTRL, SERVO[1], enable_1);
            SERVO[2]<=0;
            SERVO[3]<=0;            
        end

        else if(direction==2'b11)//SOUTH
        begin
            L_CTRL<=1; R_CTRL<=0;
            Servo S2(CLK, RESETN, L_CTRL, R_CTRL, SERVO[2], enable_2);
            Servo S3(CLK, RESETN, L_CTRL, R_CTRL, SERVO[3], enable_3);
            SERVO[0]<=0;
            SERVO[1]<=0;
        end

        else if(direction==2'b10)//WEST
        begin
            L_CTRL<=1; R_CTRL<=0;
            Servo S0(CLK, RESETN, L_CTRL, R_CTRL, SERVO[0], enable_0);
            Servo S1(CLK, RESETN, L_CTRL, R_CTRL, SERVO[1], enable_1);
            SERVO[2]<=0;
            SERVO[3]<=0;    
        end

        else if(direction==2'b00)//NORTH
        begin
            L_CTRL<=0; R_CTRL<=1;
            Servo S2(CLK, RESETN, L_CTRL, R_CTRL, SERVO[2], enable_2);
            Servo S3(CLK, RESETN, L_CTRL, R_CTRL, SERVO[3], enable_3);
            SERVO[0]<=0;
            SERVO[1]<=0;
        end
    end 
endmodule
```

I guess calling module in side always block causes error. Are there any alternative algorithm/method to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Im not 100% sure what output you want from your `Servo_Motor` module, there seems to be alot of misunderstanding of how Verilog synthesizes into an FPGA configuration. First and foremost, as you recognize, you cannot instantiate modules in `always` blocks; see this answer for an explanation of modules and how they should be used:

[How can i instantiate a module inside an if statement in verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354957/how-can-i-instantiate-a-module-inside-an-if-statement-in-verilog/30355723#30355723)

Basically, modules are structures within the design that perform a specific task, they are not called like functions. In terms of an FPGA, they are a description of a block of hardware and how it must behave, what registers it has, etc. In your current code, you are trying to call them to perform a task and then "return" the result, when you need to be instantiating them (so they exist independent of the `direction`) and either using their output or not depending on the `direction`.

A few other pointers:

1) The `Servo` module doesnt have an enable line, so you should remove it when you change where the modules are instantiated.

2) Use non-blocking assignments (`<=`) for registers (ie, clocked `always` blocks) and blocking assignments (`=`) for combinational logic (like you do for the last block in the `Servo` module, thats correct). Note, `REG` and `CNT` need to be switched to NBA.

3) For the last block (and any other combinational `always` blocks), use `always @(*)` rather than `always @(CNT or REG)`, its better to have implicit sensitivity lists rather than explicit to avoid latching

4) `RESETN` suggests an asserted low reset, while you implement an asserted high reset. Either make the net named `RESET` or which them to use `negedge` and `if (~RESETN)`

5) `integer` type is designated only to be used in simulation, make these `reg [31:0]` instead (or however many bits you really need).

Hope this helps clarify some points, thinking in RTL is very different than programming.